# Search With AMP HTML Possible?

Tags: search, amp-html

I would just love to try creating an AMP HTML website. However, what I cannot miss is our search function.

From what I understand so far, a search (input field, JavaScript handler) would not be possible with AMP HTML.

Is there any way to provide a neat search functionality within AMP HTML? Maybe using the `amp-list` component?

Comment: You could try using `amp-iframe`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Forms are supported in AMP via the [amp-form](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/) component. Using amp-form, you can embed a search form into your AMPs and render the search results into a new AMP on your server.

This is a search form in AMP:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
      <!-- ... AMP boilerplate ... -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" action="https://example.com/search" target="_top">
          <input name="search" type="search">
          <input type="submit" value="">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://example.com/search can then render to an AMP page showing the search results:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <!-- ... AMP boilerplate ... -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Results</h1>
        <ul>
           <li>Result 1</li>
           <li>Result 2</li>    
        </ul>            
    </body>
</html>
```

You can find a working sample for a search implemented with AMP [here](https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/product_listing/preview/).

Answer (score 2):

Form support will come eventually. Please file a on Github with your use case: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

There is a placeholder issue on Github to capture intent and use cases for Forms, see: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/1286